# ¿Es necesario inicializar el anuncio en adMob?

Tags: android, admob

Tengo dos apps en el play store y en una no uso

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);
```

Y en otra si, ¿podrían explicar la diferencia entre hacerlo o no? Ambas cargan la publicidad perfectamente y no tengo ningún tipo de advertencia por parte de adMob

La [documentación de admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) dice que tenemos que hacerlo, pero yo no lo hago y funciona.

Comment: Puedes agregar tu código?

Comment: Es simplemente este `MobileAds.initialize(this, APP_ID);`con mi ID, eso es lo único que incluyo en una app y en otra no, según la documentación sirve para inicializar el anuncio, pero sin inicializarlo también lo muestra

Comment: Ese método inicializa la primera instancia mas rápido, sin agregarlo, el primer anuncio tarda unos milisegundos más en aparecer. Por ejemplo, inicias el SDK de admob llamando a dicho método y para cuando llegue la parte del código donde cargas el anuncio, este ya podrá mostrarse. No hay ningún problema si no lo usas.

Comment: Y da igual donde lo inicialice? Por ejemplo, si tengo un activity_launcher y lo inicializo ahí ya me cargará todas las ads más rápido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad con el anterior método se realizaba también la inicialización del Anuncio, esto mediante el `ad_unit_id` que definia un formato y tipo de anuncio, mediante el cual configurábamos nuestro `AdView` :

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView      
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" >
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Ahora la actual implementación requiere [AdMob con Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start)  y esta implementación requiere lo que comentas, la inicialización de esta forma:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");
    }
    ...
}
```

**Ambos métodos requieren la inicialización**, anteriormente se usaba el Ad unit id y ahora se usa el  [AdMob app ID](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6232340) que es un ID único asignado a tus aplicaciones cuando se agregan a AdMob. .

> **app ID**: es un número de ID único asignado a tus aplicaciones cuando se agregan a AdMob. El ID de la aplicación se usa para identificar tus
>   aplicaciones.
>
> **ad unit ID**: es un número de ID único asignado a cada uno de sus bloques de anuncios cuando se crean en AdMob. El ID del bloque de
>   anuncios se agrega al código de su aplicación y se usa para
>   identificar las solicitudes de anuncios del bloque de anuncios.

Comment: Cabe destacar que aun se pueden usar ambos métodos, aunque en la documentación haya desaparecido el primero que comentas, gracias por el aporte

Comment: @Orz así es, por el momento usando el SDK 25 puedo comprobar que funciona, pero en un futuro seguramente será un método obsoleto ya que tendremos que migrar a Firebase como ha sucedido por ejemplo con las notificaciones, saludos.